# Why is the Keyword `as` Needed When Narrowing TypeScript Interfaces With an `if`?

Tags: typescript

Given some **interfaces** for `Circle` and `Square` as follows:

```js
export default interface Circle {
  radius: number;
}
```

```js
export default interface Square {
  sideLength: number;
}
```

I can use `as` to calculate the area properly:

```js
function getArea(shape: Circle | Square) {
  if ((shape as Circle).radius) {
    return Math.PI * (shape as Circle).radius ** 2;
  }

  return (shape as Square).sideLength ** 2;
}

const cir = { radius: 5 };
const sq = { sideLength: 4 };

console.log(getArea(cir), getArea(sq));
```

However, why can't I simplify the code like this?

```js
function getArea(shape: Circle | Square) {
  return shape.radius ? Math.PI * (shape as Circle).radius ** 2 : shape.sideLength ** 2;
}
```

My linter (which is `"strict"`) complains that: `Property 'radius' does not exist on type 'Square'`

EXACTLY!  That's why I am doing the conditional checks in my attempted simplification! This is what **narrowing,** is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't let you access values that aren't part of the type, even if the only thing you do after accessing it is pass it into a conditional. Instead, you should use the `in` operator to do your check:

```
function getArea(shape: Circle | Square) {
  if ("radius" in shape) {
    return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
  }

  return shape.sideLength ** 2;
}

// Or:
function getArea(shape: Circle | Square) {
  return "radius" in shape ? Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2 : shape.sideLength ** 2;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucooN4CwAUMsgM7AAmEAMhCAOZgAWAXMiJgLYBG0A3MQC%20xYqEixEKAMLAoCADb5ipKHErBMZdp14DhoojEwgEYYAHsQyBhDABBXHAAUZZnAAOEdrPlLkAD5oWDgQAJTIhCTIwDDIzgBEahpaCTHWbp7hkSqkyLhgmFDWALJwLAB0AAoAksgAVOTuXhXJmmQNjQBMgtEiRLkFRRnNEBUU1HSMLJ3IPQYDRAhWZGDICHLIALyR%20ert7ACsyEK9yyCr5OjbuxO09ExsyAAsJ73E52QWShUKFgzOWwOJzODZQMIAGhsdkcEBcZHQYTC-CAA)

---

Alternatively, you could rework your types so that you have a discriminated union. By that i mean, that all of the interfaces have a common property, which can be used to distinguish what type we're dealing with:

```
interface Square {
  type: 'square';
  sideLength: number;
}

interface Circle {
  type: 'circle';
  radius: number;
}

function getArea(shape: Circle | Square) {
  if (shape.type === 'circle') {
    return Math.PI * shape.radius ** 2;
  }

  return shape.sideLength ** 2;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoEcCucooN4CwAUMsmAJ4AOEAXMgOQDOWOE9A3MaY8ACYQAZCCADmYABZ0QmALYAjaJyIBfYsVCRYiFAGFgUBABt8XMlVoME%20o2yWkocXsEyMpshVCWqixGJhAIYMAA9iDIIhBgAIK4cAAUjOJw1HR6BsbIAD5oLLgAlMiEJMjAMMgJSdQAdBTUyAC8jZbWxvQFRaT2kZhQYQCycBJVAAoAksgAVMiJyRBVDk4uk1MATHbI3qa4YD1hM9U8-EKiEsvIa8TKQA)

Comment: I like the first option - kind of. It's not as much clutter and makes sense. I still think  that I shouldn't even have to check with `in`. It should just allow me to do `if (shape.radius)`. But, . The 2nd option is covered in the docs - handbook - where they use `"kind"` **property**. Having to include that seems like too much extra clutter in the `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling this function with a `Square`? What you're doing is not a typecheck; it's an assertion.

```
shape as Circle
```

This does *not* say "check if the thing is a circle". At all. It says "I know better than the compiler; trust me, this thing is a circle". You're bypassing the type checker completely.

```
if ((shape as Circle).radius) {
  ...
}
```

In this situation, you've said "assume `shape` is a `Circle` and see if its radius is truthy". At no point did we check whether `shape` was a `Circle`. If it's not, then by the rules of Javascript we get `undefined` (which is falsy), but as far as Typescript is concerned, that situation will never happen because we told them to trust us. The compiler can't make inferences if we go around telling it it's wrong.

If we use *typechecks* instead, then Typescript's automatic flow typing rules will kick in

```
if ((shape instanceof Circle) && (shape.radius)) {
  ...
}
```

Now Typescript is the one enforcing the invariants and Typescript understands that, after the `instanceof` check, there's no way `shape` can be anything other than `Circle`. We're working with the typechecker, not reaching around it.

Comment: > Have you tried calling this function with a Square?
```typescript
const sq = { sideLength: 4 };

console.log(getArea(sq));
```

Works just fine, giving `16`. The `as` is just allowing for the check of the `radius` property.

Comment: Being an **interface** only, NS  that I would use `instanceof`.